# Sorting A Vector Of Structs According To Contained Data

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I am sorry if there is similar questions already present on the website, but am currently failing to understand certain parts of the algorithm.

I have a Struct that contains information on user account information for my game:

```
struct Account
{
    int Position;
    string Name;
    int Score;
    string Date;
    int Level;

    bool operator < (User SOMETHING, User SOMETHING)
    {
         return (SOMETHING < SOMETHING);
    }
};

vector<Account> User;
User.push_back(Account());
User.push_back(Account());
User.push_back(Account());

User[0].Position=1;
User[1].Position=2;
User[2].Position=3;

sort(User.begin(), User.end(), Account);
```

I need each struct of my vector to be to be organized, say for instance, in descending/ascending order for the "Position" value that each contains.

**I just need help on (1) bool operator function (e.g. parameters and return values), and (2) How do I have it so that I can sort it by multiple variables like the positions, scores & level. (Would I need to have 3 bool operator functions?)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), something like this:

```
struct Account
{
    int Position;
    string Name;
    int Score;
    string Date;
    int Level;
};

bool operator < (const Account& lhs, const Account& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.Name,lhs.Score,lhs.Date) < std::tie(rhs.Name,rhs.Score,rhs.Date);
}
```

will sort according to `Name` first, if `Name` is equal then according to `Score`, when both `Name` and `Score` are equal then according to `Date`.

Sorting is simply done by:

```
std::sort(User.begin(), User.end());
```

Which, by default, uses `operator<` on the contained objects of type `Account`.

---

Update: I misunderstood your question. In your case you need separated comparators, e.g.

```
struct by_name_ascending
{
    bool operator()(const Account& lhs, const Account& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.Name < rhs.Name;
    }
};

struct by_score_descending
{
    bool operator()(const Account& lhs, const Account& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.Score > rhs.Score;
    }
};
```

and sort the vector with

```
std::sort(User.begin(), User.end(), by_name_ascending());
```

---

With lambdas, you could also use

```
std::sort(User.begin(), User.end(),
  [](const Account& lhs, const Account& rhs){
    return lhs.Name < rhs.Name;
  }
);
```

directly, simply switching `<` and `>` for ascending/descending. No need for other helpers or operators in the class/struct itself.

Comment: I actually need them sorted (1) by 1 variable at a time (Positions, or Scores, or Dates), and (2) Either ascending or descending.